# Decorators: passing variables from the deepest level to the top level decorator

Tags: python, runtime, decorator, on-the-fly

I'm facing a strange problem for which I request your help. Here are the details:-

While understanding decorators and applying them in my work, I have this scenario:-

```
def f3(funcA, **kw): ## Decorates f2 and acts like a prerequisite for f2 to work   
    ## code to setup pre-conditions ##   
    requestObj = GetRequestObj()
    kw['requestObj']=requestObj  
    def inner(funcB, **k):
        k.update(kw)
        ## do something ##
        return funcA(funcB, **k)   
    return inner



def f2(func, **kw): # decorates f1 and acts like a prerequisite for f1 to work
    kw['serverObject']=kw['requestObj'].GetServerObject()
    def inner(**k):
       k.update(kw)
       return func(**k)
    return inner

f2=f3(f2)

def f1(**kw):   
   ##Do something on the requestObj and serverObj in kw

f1=f2(f1)
```

Here, I understand that f1 and f2 will be the decorated functions. And, things were working till now.
Now, I have a requirement that in `function f3`, I should be calling the `code to setup pre-conditions` optionally based on a parameter which should be passed through a call from `f1` i.e. `f1` decides whether the `code to setup pre-conditions` in f3 runs or not.
**PS:** I need to call `f1` like: `f1(setup_pre_conditions=True)`

**My solution:**
I could think of putting all these functions in a class and setting a `flag` variable on the fly to `True` or `False` and using the flag variable in `f3` to decide whether `code to setup pre-conditions` should be called or not. But, using this method, I'll have to create a new object of this class everytime.

---

**Edit**
I just thought of another solution. May be you can guide me if it is correct!

Lets put all the code in the inner functions, so that they have full control which can reach from the top to the lowest level of chained decorators

---

Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: IMHO, decorating decorators seems like overly complicated way to accomplish what you want to do. I'd start by writing the simplest thing that works first, the refactor it _if necessary_.

Comment: I agree. But, this is a prototype for a huge callback based library and it begins with such simple problems to address. And, currently, I'm refactoring the original so as to suit the design that I've discussed.

Comment: decorators don't work this way. by the time you are calling the decorated `f1`, `f3` has already been run. if you want, put print statements and see when the various sections of code are called to understand what's going on.

Comment: but, if you wanted to, you could use a special keyword arg to store all the precondition/setup stuff you want, pass that down to all the decorated functions, and have the bottom level determine whether or not it wants to use it. but that would be ugly.

Comment: That is also not possibile because in each decorator, I'm trying to get an object and pass it down to the next decorator. And, as per using your method, the pre-condition will be setup immediately before the actual function, which will be too late, again :(